# I need a package both as a devDependency and dependency

Tags: javascript, npm

I ran into the issue that I need the same package as a `dependency` as well as `devDependency`.

The packages in question are `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-env`.

**Why?**

Because my package provides an interface to transpile some other part of the project in the future:

- Project source is transpiled with babel (this is the dev dependency part).
- Transpiled source code is published on NPM.
- In a second step the transpiled project source from npm is ran through webpack (webpack uses `babel-loader` and therefore needs `@babel/core`). This step is done by the end user via `webpack`.

I want to include every dev-asset (except webpack) in the package so that the end user doesn't need to install `babel-loader`, `@babel/core` etc..

I thought about just adding them as dependencies, but this seems unclean.

Maybe this is an `X/Y` problem?

What works is:

- Create another package called `xxx-dev-dependencies`.
- Add the dependencies for the webpack transpilation step to that package.
- Require the package and pass the modules to webpack.

**BUT** ... I always get this warning when installing the dev dependency package:

> babel-loader@8.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@>=2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Even though I added webpack to `peerDependencies` like this:

```
  "name": "xxx-dev-dependencies",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.x"
  }
```

Comment: You can safely ignore this warning - your users will always have Webpack installed as part of their own project.

Comment: Yes but it gets quite annoying when the same warning pops up multiple times.

Comment: For every loader I add npm emits a warning. Also, why litter the console with unnecessary / misleading warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but it's still a bit hacky:

- my-project

  - Dev Dependencies

    - `@babel/core`
    - `@babel/preset-env`
    - `my-project-dev-deps`
- my-project-dev-deps

  - Dependencies

    - `@babel/core`
    - `@babel/preset-env`
    - `babel-loader`
    - `webpack` (used to silence peer dependency warning)
  - Peer dependencies

    - `webpack` (use to ensure that end user actually has webpack installed)

`my-project-dev-deps` simply exports the dependencies like this:

```js
var path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    babel: {
        loader: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "babel-loader"),
        presets: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "@babel", "preset-env")
        ]
    }
}
```

`my-project` then requires `my-project-dev-deps` and uses it like this:

```js
var dep = require("my-project-dev-deps")
// ..
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
            loader: dep.babel.loader,
            options: {
                presets: dep.babel.presets
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I have manually verified that webpack will use the `@babel/core` version included in the `my-project-dev-deps` package.